# Derive from template constructor of template base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11

Just curious, is it ever possible to inherit from a template class and in constructor of the derived class, call constructor of the base class which is also templated and has no arguments to deduce its types from?

```
template<typename T>
struct Base {
    template<typename D>
    Base() {                // no argument of type D to infer from
        static_assert(std::is_same<T,D>::value, "");
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<int> {
    Derived()  : Base<int>::Base<int>() {} // is there a way to write it correctly?
};
```

I can replace template constructor by a template method in my particular case, but still it is an interesting question about the language flexibility.

Comment: It's not possible to explicitly specify template arguments for a constructor. So no, you can't do that.

Comment: It looks paranoid (Making sure, a derived class is using the base class properly)

Comment: It's not if you'd imagine that Base class uses compile-time information to choose different actions for its construction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the C++ standard says about this (section 14.8.1):

> [ Note:  Because the explicit template argument list follows the function template name, and because conversion member function templates and constructor member function templates are called without using a function name, there is no way to provide an explicit template argument list for these function templates. — end note ]

It's a note, not a rule, because it actually is a consequence of two other rules, one in the same section:

> Template arguments can be speciﬁed when referring to a function template specialization by qualifying the function template name  with  the  list  of  template-arguments  in  the  same  way  as  template-arguments are speciﬁed in uses of a class template specialization.

and from 12.1

> Constructors do not have names.

Answer (score 4):

The template arguments of constructor templates *must* be deduced from their arguments, it's not possible to explicitly specify template arguments for constructors.

As such, have `Base` take a dummy parameter that deduces the argument:

```
template <typename T>
struct dummy { }; // to prevent instantiation of T

template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    template <typename D>
    Base(dummy<D>)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, D>::value, "");
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<int>
{
    Derived() : Base<int>(dummy<int>{}) { }
};
```

Comment: Which is tag dispatching (avoid dummy dispatching)

Comment: Thanks, in my particular case it is not convenient because Base constructor has variadic arguments already and D is also variadic :) I can update the question if it brings additional value to it

Comment: @Anton Then make `dummy` variadic.

Comment: @DieterLücking Are you referring to the terminology? So *this* is called "tag dispatching"?

Comment: @Anton Does it not help to make `dummy` also variadic?

Answer (score 1):

By the way the question is formulated it looks going towards a nonsensical paranoia.

Just think for plain classes:

```
class Base 
{
public:
    Base() {}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived() //< default ctor
      :Base  //< this is the Base type
           () //< this selects what ctor to call
    {}
};
```

Note that you call `:Base()`, that resolve into `Base::Base()`, not `:Base::Base()`

Now, by templetizing `Base::Base()` you are in fact trying to admit that there can be many different default ctor (with `()`) for Base. That's a nonsense respect ot the concept itself of "*default*".

Even if Base is not by itself a template, this is not possible:

```
class Base
{
public:
   template<class T>
   Base() {} //< are there infinite way to default construct Base ?!?
};

Base b; //< so how is b constructed ?
```

Thing gets only apparently different with varadics:

```
template<class T>
class Base
{
public:
    template<class... S>
    Base(S&&... s) { /* something to do */ }
};

class Derived: public Base<int>
{
public:
   template<class... S>
   Derived(S&&... s) //< Derived varadicly initialized
         :Base //< base type ...
         (std::forward<S>(s)...) //< ... to initialize with what
   {}
};
```

Note that in case `s` is empty you are in fact calling `Base::Base()` from `Derived()::Derived()`, templetized with `<>` (no args)