# Can a class have a templated constructor without arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a desire to have a class that looks like:

```
template <typename T>
class foo
{
  public:
    template <typename S>
    foo()
    {
      //...
    }
};
```

but I cannot figure out how to call the constructor.  Obviously, I can make this work by giving foo() an argument of type S but can it be done without any arguments?

--Ron

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553803/derive-from-template-constuctor-of-template-base-class

Answer (score 6):

You can't pass template arguments explicitly to a constructor template. Constructors don't have names (let's not get into word games). However, that doesn't mean that you can't accomplish whatever it is you're trying to accomplish. You could pass `S` in via a class template parameter, or take a tag function parameter in the constructor to deduce `S` by. Or facilitate a factory function instead.

Comment: "You can't five template arguments to a constructor template": False. See constructor of vector which can be initialized with a pair of iterators. See (4) at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: You can't pass template arguments **explicitly** to a constructor template.  Constructors can be templated, but all template arguments have to be inferred.

Comment: @Notinlist: Your answer is not C++.

Comment: I just want to say constructors do have names, and not allowing templated constructors to be called without parenthesis params is dumb. In fact allowing me to create what I cant use is dumb. Cpp team need to rectify alot of their absurdities.

Answer (score 2):

That works for me on gcc 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-3)

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    template<typename U>
    A()
        : t(U())
    { }
private:
    T t;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    A<float> a(A<float>::A<int>());
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `g++ -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic tc.cpp -o tc`, no warnings.

**UPDATE**: This solution is wrong. It is explained in the comments. I consider it a useful bad solution and I would like to keep it here.

Comment: Actually what you're doing [shouldn't even compile](http://ideone.com/AJ90Rz)... sounds like a buggy g++.

Comment: Lol. `A<float>::A<int>` is equivalent to `A<int>`. Check it with `std::is_same`. ;)

Comment: An explicit argument list follows the name of the template, but **"Constructors do not have names."**.

Comment: Direct quote from the Standard, section 14.8.1: "[ Note:  Because the explicit template argument list follows the function template name, and because conversion member function templates and constructor member function templates are called without using a function name, there is no way to provide an explicit template argument list for these function templates. — end note ]"

Comment: Compiles in clang but not g++ versions later than 4.4. In any event, all compilers that compiles this code parses `A<float> a(A<float>::A<int>());` by considering `A<float>::A` as a *injected-class-name* used as a *template-name*, making `A<float>::A<int>` exactly equivalent to `A<int>` and the entire statement a function declaration (due to the most vexing parse). For example - http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/m0rQjY45u0vGUs9t.

Comment: You are right. I let myself mislead. Sorry!

Comment: @T.C. Actually, I'm fairly sure that `A<float>::A<int>` **should** compile. I'm gonna check the standard.

Comment: I think this answer should stay here with the comments as a useful bad solution. How will it stay here without me loosing gazillion reputations?

Comment: @T.C : yes and clang actually warns about it : `prog.cc:16:15: warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]`