# Injected-class-names of class templates

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Inspired by [the code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557065/can-a-class-have-a-templated-constructor-without-arguments/26557271).  Consider:

```
template<class>
class A { };

int main()
{
    A<float> a(A<float>::A<int>());
    return 0;
}
```

Is this code

1. ill-formed, because `A<float>::A` names the constructor (per §3.4.3.1 [class.qual]/p2) and cannot be used in this context (plus the `<int>` would complete fail to parse anyway), or
2. well-formed, with `A<float>::A` being the *injected-class-name*, used as a *template-name* (§14.6.1 [temp.local]), such that `A<float>::A<int>` means exactly the same as `A<int>`, and `a` being declared as a function (due to the most vexing parse)?

[g++ says 1. clang says 2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b04ea755f4a0d85c), and so does [ICC 13](http://goo.gl/KT0NHo). Which compiler is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### `gcc` is correct; your snippet is ill-formed!

```
// reduced testcase
template<class T>
class A { };

int main () {
  A<float>::A<int> x; // ill-formed, bug in `clang` and `icc`
}
```

In the above reduced testcase we have a *nested-name-specifier*, `A<float>::`, followed by an *unqualified-id* `A`, which is then followed by some gibberish (`<int>`).

This is because the context in which the *nested-name-specifier* appears mandates that, during a look-up, function names are included (meaning that the constructor is found first, and the expression is ill-formed).

**Relevant Bug Reports**:

- [llvm.org/bugs/ - **#8263; Incorrect constructor name resolution**](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8263)

---

#### How to circumvent the "*problem*"?

There are contexts in which member names that are looked up through a *nested-name-specifier* (that nominates a class) shall not include functions (hence, contexts where the constructor is not found), below are a few examples:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
  typedef T value_type;
};
```

```
  struct A<float>::A<int>  x;     // ok, context: elaborate-type-specifier
typename A<float>::A<int> ();     // ok, context: [expr.type.conv]p1
  A<float>::A::value_type  x;     // ok, context: nested-name-specifier


struct X : A<float>::A<int> { };  // ok, context: base-specifier
```

---

#### What does the Standard say?

> `3.4.3.1p2` **Class members** `[class.qual]`
>
> > In a lookup in which function names are not ignored<sup>88</sup> and the *nested-name-specifier* nominates a class *C*:
> >
> > - if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier*, when looked up in *C*, is the injected-class-name of *C* (Clause 9), or
> > - in a *using-declaration* (7.3.3) that is a *member-declaration*, if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier* is the same as the *identifier* or the *simple-template-id*'s *template-name* in the last component of the *nested-name-specicifier,
> >
> > the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class *C*.
> >
> > [ *Note*: ... ]
> >
> > Such a constructor name shall be used only in the *declarator-id* of a declaration that names a constructor or in a *using-declaration*.
> >
> > ---
> >
> > <sup><sup>88.</sup> Lookups in which function names are ignored include names appearing in a *nested-name-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-specifier*, or a *base-specifier*.</sup>

> `14.6.1p2` **Locally declared names** `[temp.local]`
>
> > Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name
> >     (Clause 9). The injected-class-name can be used as a *template-name* or a
> >     *type-name*.
> >
> > When it is used with a *template-argument-list*, as a
> >     *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter*, or as the final
> >     identifier in the *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class template
> >     declaration, it refers to the class template itself.
> >
> > Otherwise, it is
> >     equivalent to the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the 
> >     class template enclosed in `<>`.