# Program being compiled differently in 3 major C++ compilers. Which one is right?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

As an interesting follow-up (not of big practical importance though) to my previous question:
[Why does C++ allow us to surround the variable name in parentheses when declaring a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675601/why-does-c-allow-us-to-surround-the-variable-name-in-parentheses-when-declarin)

I found out that combining the declaration in parentheses with [injected class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/c-why-is-there-injected-class-name/25549691#25549691) feature may lead to surprising results regarding compiler behavior.

Take a look at the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
struct B
{
};

struct C
{
  C (){ std::cout << "C" << '\n'; }
  C (B *) { std::cout << "C (B *)" << '\n';}
};

B *y = nullptr;
int main()
{
  C::C (y);
}
```

1. Compiling with g++ 4.9.2 gives me the following compilation error:

   ```
   main.cpp:16:10: error: cannot call constructor 'C::C' directly [-fpermissive]
   ```
2. It compiles successfully with MSVC2013/2015 and prints `C (B *)`
3. It compiles successfully with clang 3.5 and prints `C`

So obligatory question is which one is right? :)

*(I strongly swayed towards clang version though and msvc way to stop declaring variable after just changing type with technically its typedef seems kind of weird)*

Comment: `C::C y;` doesn't make sense, right?   Neither does `C::C (y);`  At first I thought this was an instance of Most-Vexing-Parse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse, but now I think it's just undefined behavior meaning all three compilers are "right."

Comment: #3 clang is definitely wrong, #2 msvc is too permissive and #1 g++ is right ( (I guess)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558507/injected-class-names-of-class-templates

Comment: `C::C` does not name a type it names a function, so GCC is right imo.

Comment: [Filed as a bug on connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1253133)

Comment: [Filed as a clang bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23254).

Comment: ICC, FWIW, agrees with GCC on this: http://goo.gl/CkPZmW

Answer (score 92, accepted):

GCC is correct, at least according to C++11 lookup rules. 3.4.3.1 [class.qual]/2 specifies that, if the nested name specifier is the same as the class name, it refers to the constructor not the injected class name. It gives examples:

```
B::A ba;           // object of type A
A::A a;            // error, A::A is not a type name
struct A::A a2;    // object of type A
```

It looks like MSVC misinterprets it as function-style cast expression creating a temporary `C` with `y` as a constructor parameter; and Clang misinterprets it as a declaration of a variable called `y` of type `C`.

Comment: Yes, 3.4.3.1/2 is the key. Good job!

Comment: It says "In a lookup in which function names are not ignored". It seems to me that in the examples given, in particular `A::A a;`, function names should be ignored - or not?

Comment: Going by the numbering in N4296, the key is really 3.4.3.1/2.1: "if the name specified after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in C, is the injected-class-name of C [ ...] the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C." Mike's summary is a little over-simplified though--for example, a typedef of the class-name inside the class would allow a nested name specifier different from the class name to still refer to the class name, so it would still refer to the ctor.

Comment: _"It says 'In a lookup in which function names are not ignored'."_ Only since C++14. I can't speak to how this may affect this answer as I am not familiar with the "ignoring function names" terminology, but the given example in that paragraph has not changed. So I'm going to say "it doesn't".

Comment: Can someone try this on VS2015 so I can file the bug on connect?

Comment: @Mgetz: From the question: _"It compiles successfully with MSVC2013/2015 and prints `C (B *)`"_.

Comment: @Columbo No, it isn't ignored. (If function names were ignored, then it would work even if the type name was hidden by a function name.)

Comment: For completeness this should clarify whether it is ill-formed with diagnostic required, or ill-formed with no diagnostic required. If the latter then all compilers are "right".

Answer (score 16):

G++ is correct as it gives an error. Because the constructor could not be called directly in such a format without `new` operator. And although your code calls `C::C`, it looks like an constructor call. However, according to the C++11 standard 3.4.3.1, this is not a legal function call, or a type name ([see Mike Seymour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29681754/566459)).

Clang is wrong since it even does not call the correct function.

MSVC is something reasonable, but still it does not follow the standard.

Comment: What does `new` operator change?

Comment: @NeilKirk: A lot, for people who think that `new B(1,2,3)` is some kind of "direct constructor call" (which, of course, it is not) as distinct from the temporary instantiation `B(1,2,3)` or the declaration `B b(1,2,3)`.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit How would you describe what `new B(1,2,3)` is?

Comment: @user2030677: A new-expression, using the keyword `new`, a type name, and a constructor argument list. It's still not a "direct constructor call".

Comment: "Clang is wrong since it even does not call the correct function.": I think (because the OP's remark about parentheses in declarations) that Clang interpretes `C::C (y);`  as `C::C y;`, i.e. a defintion of a variable y of type C (using the injected type C::C while erroneously ignoring the increasingly insane language specification's 3.4.1,2 which makes C::C the constructor). That is not quite a glaring error as you seem to think, imo.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If new B(1,2,3) isn't some kind of direct constructor call then exactly what it is?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: See this program also: http://ideone.com/2HjCeZ. Constructor is being clearly called in the program when I write new Test(3,6). I am confused due to ur comments. Will you please clear the doubts?

Comment: @PravasiMeet: That the constructor is invoked doesn't mean `new B(1,2,3)` is "a direct constructor" call, any more than any other means of constructing an object is "a direct constructor call". You are surely aware that `new` does other things?