# Where in the Standard (C++14) does it say that the following two declarations are equivalent?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

```
struct A{};
int A;
struct A a;
struct A::A b;
```

The last two declarations above are equivalent.They both declare objects of type A. Where in the Standard can I find or deduce this?

Comment: I think there may be cases where those last two are _not_ equivalent...

Comment: Are you looking for the specification of the *injected class name* used in the second? Or the specification that the *elaborated type name* `struct A` refers unambiguously to the type, not the variable?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Indeed, if there's a namespace `A` containing a different class `A`, then the second would denote that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @Columbo: [I disagree](http://ideone.com/x3HSoR). You can't declare the namespace in the same scope as the class, but you can bring it into scope with `using`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour [Clang disagrees with you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bae3ed6ce75527fb)

Comment: @Columbo: Good for Clang. Unfortunately, it's too late on a Friday for me to care which is right.

Comment: @MikeSeymour http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883977/ambiguous-name-lookup-with-using-directive So yeah, not possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[class]/2:

> A *class-name* is inserted into the scope in which it is declared
>   immediately after the class-name is seen. **The *class-name* is also
>   inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the
>   *injected-class-name*.**

I.e. `A::A::A::A` refers to `A` as well. In some contexts, `A::A` could name the constructor instead, though - [class.qual]/2 covers this, and its note even addresses your example:

> In a lookup in which function names are not ignored<sup>33</sup> and
>   the *nested-name-specifier* nominates a class `C`
>
> - if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier*, when looked up in `C`, is the *injected-class-name*
>            of `C` (Clause 9), or
> - in a *using-declaration* (7.3.3) that is a *member-declaration*, if the name specified after the *nested-name-
>          specifier* is the same as the identifier or the *simple-template-id*’s *template-name* in the last component
>               of the *nested-name-specifier*,
>
> **the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class `C`**. [ *Note:* **For example, the constructor is not an acceptable
>   lookup result in an *elaborated-type-specifier* so the constructor
>   would not be used in place of the *injected-class-name*.** *— end
>   note* ]
>
> ---
>
> <sup>33)</sup> Lookups in which function names are ignored include
>   names appearing in a *nested-name-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-
>   specifier*, or a *base-specifier*.

So in a statement such as

```
A::A a;
```

Function names are **not** ignored when looking up `A::A`, and thus the code is ill-formed as `A::A` refers to the constructor. However, in

```
struct B : A::A {};
struct A::A a;
```

Everything is fine as function names are ignored in base-specifiers and elaborated-type-specifiers.

Comment: I know this paragraph. But how did you deduce from it that A::A is equivalent to the type A in the above declaration?

Comment: @Leon That’s what that paragraph says.

Comment: @LeonTrotski ... the name `A` is declared inside the scope of the class `A`, hence the qualified-id `A::A` can refer to said name.

Comment: Doesn't `A::A` always refer to the constructor, unless a disambiguating `struct` precedes it?

Comment: @Columbo But why the declaration `A::A *p1;` is not valid, as in `struct A{}; A::A *p1; A* p2;`?

Comment: @LeonTrotski: That's a context in which function names are not ignored. In that context, it refers to the constructor (see section 3.4.3.1) ([and this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681449/program-being-compiled-differently-in-3-major-c-compilers-which-one-is-right/29681754#29681754)).

Comment: @LeonTrotski Because that's one of the contexts where `A::A` is naming the constructor instead :)

Comment: @Columbo: Great, thanks! I just found that `A::A` should refer to the class, not the constructor, in "a *nested-name-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-specifier*, or a *base-specifier*." For example: `struct B : A::A {};` (here `A::A` refers to the class, not the constructor). You are right indeed!

Comment: @Columbo Let me see if I understood this correctly. So you're saying that `A::A a;` is ill-formed because of footnote (33) and the fact that this declaration doesn't define a constructor for `A`?

Comment: @LeonTrotski Err, what!? Not quite. `A::A a;` is ill-formed because `A::A` names the (implicitly-declared) constructor of `A` but not the type `A`, since function names are not ignored in this context.

Comment: `function names are not ignored in this context` - and that is because of footnote 33. Isn't that true? Also, if the declaration `A::A a;` were replaced by `A::A(){}`, it would be valid because it would define the constructor for `A`. That's what I said in my prior comment.

Comment: @LeonTrotski Footnotes aren't normative, anyway. Also, yeah, I partially misunderstood your comment then.