# Ambiguous name lookup with using-directive

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, name-lookup, qualified-name

It's not allowed to put a namespace and a class with the same name into one declarative region, i.e.

```
namespace A {}
class A{};
```

[is ill-formed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b837907b4d0609c) (see §3.3.1/4). However, one can introduce the name of either one via a using-directive:

```
namespace N { namespace A {int i;} }

struct A {static int i;};

using namespace N;

int i = A::i; // The global struct, or namespace N::A?
```

Is this code ill-formed? VC++ [**thinks so**](http://rextester.com/WACF61238), as well as [**Clang**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf8c136996f85060):

> ```
> main.cpp:7:9: error: reference to 'A' is ambiguous
> int i = A::i;
>         ^
> main.cpp:3:8: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'A'
> struct A {static int i;};
>        ^
> main.cpp:1:25: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'N::A'
> namespace N { namespace A {int i;} }
>                         ^
> ```

However, [**GCC accepts it**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd6f5f9387cb818a).

Who is right?

Comment: GCC picks `N::A::i`. Wonder why.

Comment: @Barry I'm just as confused, since I expected it to prefer the declaration that is more superficial, i.e. "closer" to the point of lookup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is ill-formed. When looking up `A`, §7.3.4/6 steps in:

> If name lookup finds a declaration for a name in two different
>   namespaces, and the declarations do not declare the same entity and do
>   not declare functions, the use of the name is ill-formed.

Here, the namespaces are the global namespace and `N`, and the entities are the namespace `N::A` and the class `::A`.