# Injected class name compiler discrepancy

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, c++14

Consider this code:

```
struct foo{};

int main() {
    foo::foo a;
}
```

I would expect this to be well-formed, declaring a variable of type `foo` by the rule in [class]/2 (N4140, emphasis mine):

> A *class-name* is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the *class-name* is seen.
>   **The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself**; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.
>   For purposes of access checking, the injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name.

[`clang 3.6.0`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f2622297cbb99e6) agrees with me, compiling the above code with no applicable warnings with `-Wall -pedantic`.

[`gcc 5.2.0`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e507bb6594ccae93) disagrees, providing the following error message:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:5: error: 'foo::foo' names the constructor, not the type
   foo::foo a;
```

The above holds no matter how deep the nesting of injected class names, e.g. `foo::foo::foo::foo`.

Is there a rule which forces that construct to be interpreted as a constructor in that context, or is this a`gcc` bug? Or am I interpreting the standards quote incorrectly?

Comment: Clang has a number of bugs with its handling of injected-class-names. This is one of them.

Comment: Very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681449/program-being-compiled-differently-in-3-major-c-compilers-which-one-is-right

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that `clang` is wrong in this case. The relevant exception I was looking for is in [class.qual]/2:

> 2 In a lookup in which function names are not ignored and the nested-name-specifier nominates a class C:
>
> - (2.1)
>     **if the name specified after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in C, is the injected-class-name of C**, or
> - [...]
>
> **the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C.**

The standard has a near-equivalent (non-normative, obviously) example:

```
struct A { A(); };
struct B: public A { B(); };

A::A() { }
B::B() { }

B::A ba;// object of type A
A::A a;// error, A::A is not a type name
struct A::A a2;// object of type A
```

However, `clang` actually issues a correct diagnostic in this case:

```
error: qualified reference to 'A' is a constructor name rather than a type wherever a constructor can be declared
```

Perhaps `clang` interprets the line `In a lookup in which function names are not ignored` as `In a lookup in which a constructor declaration is valid`, but that doesn't seem to be a correct interpretation.

There is an [existing bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13403) for this in the `clang` bugzilla.

Comment: My report is older and it's a rejects-valid: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8263 :p

Answer (score 7):

Relevant, but not an answer: The GCC people discussed *exactly* this [for years](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11764) and figured that it should not be accepted. They explicitly made this an error in GCC [4.5](http://goo.gl/Qkg3SN) and newer - in [4.4.7](http://goo.gl/pKmzW6) it was accepted.

BTW: You probably want to use Clang's `-Weverything` instead of `-Wall -pedantic` when investigating such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the subject of [language defect #147](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#147)
which contains this example

```
class B { };
class A: public B {
    A::B ab;       // B is the inherited injected B
    A::A aa;       // Error: A::A is the constructor
};
```

At least gcc seems to believe that. :-)

Comment: Ah, so the relevant exception is [class.qual]/2.2 and this is actually a bug in `clang`?

Comment: I'm not sure. This example is using `A::A` inside a class, while your use is inside `main`. Could be different rules there. (I just had a weak memory about the rules having been changed, and looked up the defect report).