# Is this absurd code that compiles fine a bug in both Clang and GCC?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang, language-lawyer

I was playing around with templates today to see if I could get the compiler to deduce the type of an outer class from one of its inner classes.
I didn't find my solution (which I suspect is impossible), but while trying to fix an error I ran into very strange behavior that I reduced to the following snippet.

```c++
struct A
{
    struct B{};

    template <typename T>
    struct EverythingIsFine
    {
        using Outer = T;
        using Inner = typename T::B::B::B::B::B::B;
    };

    using ItWillBeOkay = EverythingIsFine<B>; // Probably not ok
    using InnerProblem = ItWillBeOkay::Inner; // Still not ok
    using OuterProblem = decltype(B().ItWillBeOkay::Outer::B::B::B
                                     ::B::B::B::~B()); // Not even CLOSE to ok
};
```

It surprisingly compiles with no warnings and no errors with both Clang and GCC.
The versions of my compilers are `gcc version 5.3.1 20160121 (Debian 5.3.1-7)` and `Debian clang version 3.6.2-3 (tags/RELEASE_362/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.2)` and the flag used to compile are `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra`.

I observed that it also compiles fine [on Ideone with the C++14 setting](https://ideone.com/DC2kRw).

---

I then used this simple test to get the exact types of `InnerProblem` and `OuterProblem`:

```
template <class T> void Type();
int main()
{
    Type<A::InnerProblem>();
    Type<A::OuterProblem>();
}
```

And both compilers report the same types when compiling the test:

> In function `main`:
>   main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `void Type<A::B>()`
>   main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `void Type<void>()`

That is to say, the type of `InnerProblem` is `A::B` and the type of `OuterProblem` is `void`.

---

Is this somehow permitted by the standard or is it a bug in both compilers?
And since I seem to be as confused as my compiler, what is actually happening with this code?

**EDIT**: As a simplified followup, because I don't understand why two compilers can not give the same result, the following code compiles with Clang, but not with GCC.

```
struct A
{
    struct B{};

    template <typename T>
    struct EverythingIsFine
    {
        using Inner = typename T::B::B::B;
    };

    using Problem = EverythingIsFine<B>::Inner::B::B::B; // Not ok
};
```

GCC now outputs the following error:

> main.cpp:11:26: error: 'A::B::B' names the constructor, not the type
>      using InnerProblem = EverythingIsFine::Inner::B::B::B; // Not ok

Comment: This code compiles on ICC and MSVS as well

Comment: New question -> new question please. Include a link if the context helps.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I think that my new question would be a dup too, so I'll abstain this time, but you're right.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. There's a difference between the question "why is this code valid", to which the answer is "injected class name", and the question "why is the class name injected".

Comment: @PeteBecker The top answer there includes pretty much the same quote you provide, all the necessary information is there. No need to duplicate it here.

Answer (score 6):

It's valid.

> The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself;
>   this is known as the injected-class-name." (9/2).

So `B::B` names the class `B`, as does `B::B::B`, and so on.

EDIT:

So `typename B::B` names the class `B`, as does `typename B::B::B`, and so on.

Comment: That makes sense, but if I replace `InnerProblem = ItWillBeOkay::Inner` by `InnerProblem = ItWillBeOkay::Inner::B::B::B;` now GCC fails to compile and Clang still compiles fine, is this well-defined behavior? GCC says "'A::B::B' names the constructor, not the type".

Comment: @tux3 - I don't know. I didn't (and won't) follow all the nested typedefs in your question.

Comment: @tux3 I haven't looked at your crazy nested names either, but judging from the error message, that might be a clang bug, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/32006122/241631

Comment: I tried to make a simplified example to cut on the crazy nested namespaces, is this better?

Comment: @Praetorian You're right, it looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006122/injected-class-name-compiler-discrepancy now that I look at it.

Comment: `B::B` names a constructor here. There's only few contexts in which it doesn't. I.e. no, it's not valid, but Clang is bugged.

Comment: So my understanding after some reading is that this is [a bug in Clang](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13403) that GCC is correct in reporting, so I can't accept this answer.

Comment: Your update is just as incorrect. typename-specifiers are *not*  a context in which function names are ignored.