# Calling non static function or constructor using "class::func()" from outside

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, c++14

I saw this snippet on Meeting C++ (@meetingcpp)

Following code compiles fine on [clang](https://goo.gl/QDCoaQ) and MSVC (Can try [here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)) but fails on [gcc](https://goo.gl/bDI5gA) and icc.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct B {};
struct C {
    C() { cout << "C()\n"; }
    C(B *) { cout << "C(B *)\n"; }
};

B *p = nullptr;

int main() {
    C::C(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Is this a known bug in Clang and MSVC or there are any chances this code may be legal?

Type of `p` is `B *`, but `C::C` should not compile?

Comment: Still it can compile with g++ if you add the -fpermissive flag

Comment: @sestus Thanks. This means code is non-conforming.

Comment: @AngryLettuce Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in Clang, bug reports [23253](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23253), 23254 and 13403 are all reports of the issue. Ironically, this question is actually a duplicate of [Program being compiled differently in 3 major C++ compilers. Which one is right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681449/program-being-compiled-differently-in-3-major-c-compilers-which-one-is-right).

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate link, I got it.

Answer (score 3):

According to the standard 12.1/p2 Constructors [class.ctor] (**Emphasis Mine**):

> A constructor is used to initialize objects of its class type.
>   **Because constructors do not have names, they are never found during name lookup;** however an explicit type conversion using the
>   functional notation (5.2.3) will cause a constructor to be called to
>   initialize an object. [ Note: For initialization of objects of class
>   type see 12.6. — end note ]

Thus, you can't call a constructor directly, because constructors do not have names and they are never found during name lookup.

Consequently, GCC is conforming while CLANG and VC++ are not.

Comment: Ironically, the `C::C` in this case *does* refer to the constructor and *not* to the injected-class-name, and that's the reason why it's an error.