# Why is decltype(class::class::class::member) valid

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I noticed by accident that this code compiles and works correctly:

```
struct M { int some_int; };
static_assert(std::is_same<
                   decltype(M::M::M::M::some_int) /* <- this */,
                   int>::value, "Types must be int");
```

Why is this correct (`decltype(M::M::M::M::some_int) <=> decltype(M::some_int)`)?

What other constructs one can use this pattern with `class::class::...::member`?

Compiler: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23824.1 for x86

Comment: Oh boy..let the upvotes flow in for something that's obviously a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12135498).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works because of the *injected-class-name*:

> `(N3337) [class]/2:`A class-name is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the class-name is seen.
>   The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the injected-class-name.
>   For purposes of access checking, the injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name. [...]

So you can arbitrarily nest these, and they'll work with derived types as well:

```
struct A { using type = int; };
struct B : public A {};

using foo = B::B::B::A::A::A::type;
```

Note that in the case of `A[::A]*::A`, the injected-class-name can be considered to name the constructor instead:

> `[class.qual]/2:` In a lookup in which the constructor is an acceptable lookup result and the nested-name-specifier nominates
>   a class `C`:
>
> — if the name specified after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in `C`, is the injected-class-name
>   of `C` (Clause 9), or
>
> — [...]
>
> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class `C`.

Comment: *"Note that in the case of `A[::A]*::A`, the injected-class-name can be considered to name the constructor instead:"* Ib4 the natural follow-up dupe: Yes, clang tends to get this wrong. See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681449/program-being-compiled-differently-in-3-major-c-compilers-which-one-is-right).

Answer (score 10):

This is valid in all contexts, not just `decltype`. A class contains its own name as the *injected class name.* So within a class `A::B::M`, the name `M` is injected to refer to the class `A::B::M`. This means that you can then use `M::M::M::some_member` to refer to members of that class, if you really want to.

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2397cc2dd5ea3b69)

Note that when referring just to the class name itself (e.g. `M::M::M`), the situation is slightly different. If such a reference occurs in a place where a reference to a function could also potentially be correct, the syntax is taken to refer to the constructor instead. However, in type-only contexts, even such reference is valid. Example:

```
M::M::M m;  // illegal, M::M interpreted as reference to constructor

struct D : public M::M::M  // legal, a function could not be references here, so M::M::M means M
{};
```