# c++ template copy constructor not available or explicit

Tags: c++

I wrote a code with template copy constructor to get a better understanding of the concept as I am new to it but the following code fails to compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Grid
{
public:
    explicit Grid(size_t inWidth = kDefaultWidth, size_t inHeight = kDefaultHeight);
    virtual ~Grid();

    template <typename E>
    Grid(const Grid<T>& src);

    static const size_t kDefaultWidth = 10;
    static const size_t kDefaultHeight = 10;
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> mCells;
    size_t mWidth, mHeight;
};

template <typename T>
template <typename E>
Grid<T>::Grid(const Grid<T>& src)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor working " << endl;

}

int main()
{
    Grid<double> myDoubleGrid;
    Grid<double> newDoubleGrid(myDoubleGrid);
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling the above code in visual studio following error appears:-

ERROR:-

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2558   class 'Grid': no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'

I have tried to replace the argument's template with E and It shows more errors (strange ones)

```
template <typename T>
template <typename E>
Grid<T>::Grid(const Grid<E>& src)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor working " << endl;

}
```

Errors:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Grid::Grid(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (??0?$Grid@N@@QAE@II@Z) referenced in function _main
>
> Error  LNK1120 2 unresolved externals
>
> Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Grid::~Grid(void)" (??1?$Grid@N@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall Grid::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_G?$Grid@N@@UAEPAXI@Z)

Comment: Yes I have, just after the public: access specifier

Comment: `Grid<T>::Grid(const Grid<T>& src)`... `T` and `T`, what is the use of `E`?

Comment: It may be used later I was planning to use it up for some other purposes, although it is ignorable

Comment: @HarshulSharma You can’t simply add template arguments and expect that this doesn’t change the function signature.

Comment: Works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92c4cf439a926947) after adding the constructor and destructor bodies.

Comment: Actually first I had created a constructor to take a different type E i.e. Grid<E>& but that ended with very strange errors too so I tried to see If it works with simply Grid<T>& and here is the problem

Comment: It looks that MSVC decided not to generate a copy-constructor due to the presence of `Grid(const Grid<T>& src)`, which in turn is not usable due to non-deducible `E`

Comment: @NathanOliver - do you know why your code works? What is deduced for type `E`?

Comment: A template constructor is never(!) a copy constructor.

Comment: But that T template replacement for E may not be the reason for the specified error still I suggest you to try to replace T in the argument with E and see more errors

Comment: @HarshulSharma What's the purpose of  `template<typename E>` actually? You want to provide proper conversion, e.g. `Grid<float>` to `Grid<double>`?

Comment: So that  I can take Grid<int> also and create a Grid<double> instance from it

Comment: @HarshulSharma IF you want to do that you need to declare and defie the constructor as `template <typename E>
    Grid(const Grid<E>& src);`

Comment: Just as a side note, did you implement in a `.cpp` file? This looks like it's the source of all your errors.

Comment: @ NathanOliver Try to run that now...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Yes they all are in a single source file

Comment: @HarshulSharma See this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52fec9fe55565726

Comment: @ NathanOliver But it's not working in visual studio

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Are you really sure it is a duplicate ?

Comment: @HarshulSharma What version?  It works with my copy of MSVC 2015.

Comment: @ NathanOliver Not working with mine I have the same version

Comment: @Elyasin As from the error messages and what OP's stating in their comments (_"Yes they all are in a single source file "_) yes, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: g++  4.9.2 compiles it without errror!

Comment: @Roland Sure it compiles if you put everything into the same TU :-P ...

Comment: Hi all, [here's my solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a1d8e7fdae4bb09). I've made some minor changes, filled in some of the initialization lists and made some comments, which will hopefully make it clearer what's going on. It compiles fine on both g++ and clang++, for c++11 and c++14.

Comment: @Judge you should use alias names for the types rather than typedefs as they are more easy to read as well as more useful

Comment: @Harshul Sharma good point, thank you! :) [Updated code here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4b5497a55d92b3c).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A template constructor is never(!) a copy constructor. The constructor in your code is a converting constructor, only.

You may want both:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Please do not have this ugliness in a header!
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Grid
{
public:
    explicit Grid(size_t inWidth = kDefaultWidth, size_t inHeight = kDefaultHeight)
    // initialize members ...
    {}

    // Without this copy-constructor the compiler generates a copy-constructor
    // (with no output, of course)
    Grid(const Grid& src) 
    // initialize members ...
    {
        cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
    }

    template <typename E>
    Grid(const Grid<E>& src) 
    // initialize members ...
    {
        cout << "Converting constructor" << endl;
    }

    static const size_t kDefaultWidth = 10;
    static const size_t kDefaultHeight = 10;
    size_t mWidth, mHeight;
};

int main()
{
    Grid<double> myDoubleGrid;
    Grid<double> newDoubleGrid(myDoubleGrid); // Copy constructor
    Grid<int> newIntGrid(myDoubleGrid);       // Converting constructor
    return 0;
}
```

See also:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor
- [Derive from template constuctor of template base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553803/derive-from-template-constuctor-of-template-base-class)

Comment: By the way If I replace Grid(const Grid<E>& src) with Grid(const Grid<T>& src) it gives no error but how to access this <T> version ??

Comment: The `template <typename E> Grid(const Grid<T>& src);` which is `template <typename E> Grid(const Grid& src);` is useless.

Comment: But the compiler should complain that the type of <E> is not specified and complier does not provide default copy constructor

Comment: Hey by the way in this case why does'nt the compiler provide it's own copy constructor

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Grid<T>(Grid<U> const&)` is not technically a copy constructor, it is a converting constructor. The compiler still generates a copy constructor for you.

Comment: But compiler is not generating any default copy constructor that is why the error appears

Answer (score 1):

The thing to which you call as dangerous error is happening because of your silly mistakes:-

1) You have provided declarations for both constructors and destructors. And as you are saying that it is your one and only source file. It means that you must have not defined them and which is the reason for the linker errors that you are getting. Sometimes these pretty simple problems can prove to be very dangerous and time consuming.

You could have replaced the  semicolon with a pair of braces if you don't want to provide any detailed implementation.

2) The thing that you are trying to do is completely logicless as you are creating a converter constuctor with the ssignature similar to copy constructor. Anyway compiler will give preference to copy constructor than your converter constructor.

Ultimately your definition for the constructor will never actually be called.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions